# Reverse rubik's cube algorithm

Tags: java, android

I have been all day strugglingh through this simple function, but i can't get it working as I would like to. It may seem simple at first, and there is indeed another entry in Stack Overflow which talks about it. However, things get messy when brackets are introduced.
Let's say we can get an algorithm for a Rubiks cube which will look something like
(R U R' U) U' (R U' R')
It is important to note that after every move, whether it has a "'" or not, there is a space, except for those before the end brackets.
Now, for every algorithm on a Rubik's cube there exists its inverse, the one which undoes it. For example, the inverse of R is R' and of U is U, and the inverse of R U is U' R'. Thus, the inverse of the example is:
(R U R') U (U' R U' R')
It is also important to nothe that there are many moves (F, B, D, U, u, f, M, S, x, y, z...)
Also every alg has its own inverse (R has R' and vice versa,
Can you get any function in Java for that?
I have tried infinite loops of ifelse, for, switch... 
I will leave some of my tries just for reference

```
        String fullAlg = text.toString() + " ";
        String reversedAlg = "hh";
        int numSpaces = 1;
        int pos1 = 0, pos2 = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < text.length(); i++) {
            if (text.charAt(i) == ' ' && numSpaces == 0) {
                numSpaces++;
                pos1 = i;
            }

            if (text.charAt(i) == ' ' && numSpaces == 1) {
                numSpaces++;
                pos2 = i;
            }
            if (numSpaces == 2) {
                if (fullAlg.substring(pos1, pos2).matches("[a-zA-Z]+")){
                    Toast.makeText(this, "YES", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                switch (fullAlg.substring(pos1, pos2)) {

                    //Begin with (
                    case "(" + "[a-zA-Z]+":
                        reversedAlg += ")'" + fullAlg.substring(pos1, pos2).charAt(1);
                        break;
                    case "(" + "[a-zA-Z]+" + "\'":
                        reversedAlg += ")" + fullAlg.substring(pos1, pos2).charAt(1);
                        break;
                    case "(" + "[a-zA-Z]+" + "2":
                        reversedAlg += ")2" + fullAlg.substring(pos1, pos2).charAt(1);
                        break;

                    //No ()
                    case "[a-zA-Z]+":
                        reversedAlg += " '" + fullAlg.substring(pos1, pos2).charAt(0);
                        break;
                    case "[a-zA-Z]+" + "\'":
                        reversedAlg += " '" + fullAlg.substring(pos1, pos2).charAt(0);
                        break;
                    case "[a-zA-Z]+" + "2":
                        reversedAlg += " 2" + fullAlg.substring(pos1, pos2).charAt(0);
                        break;

                    //End with )
                    case "[a-zA-Z]+" + ")":
                        reversedAlg += " '" + fullAlg.substring(pos1, pos2).charAt(1) + "(";
                        break;
                    case "[a-zA-Z]+" + "\'" + ")":
                        reversedAlg += " " + fullAlg.substring(pos1, pos2).charAt(1) + "(";
                        break;
                    case "[a-zA-Z]+" + "2" + ")":
                        reversedAlg += " )2" + fullAlg.substring(pos1, pos2).charAt(1) + "(";
                        break;

                    //Encapsulated in ()
                    case "(" + "[a-zA-Z]+" + ")":
                        reversedAlg += " )'" + fullAlg.substring(pos1, pos2).charAt(1) + "(";
                        break;
                    case "(" + "[a-zA-Z]+" + "\'" + ")":
                        reversedAlg += " )" + fullAlg.substring(pos1, pos2).charAt(1) + "(";
                        break;
                    case "(" + "[a-zA-Z]+" + "2" + ")":
                        reversedAlg += " )2" + fullAlg.substring(pos1, pos2).charAt(1) + "(";
                        break;
                }
                numSpaces = 0;
            }
        }

        StringBuilder returnAlg = new StringBuilder(reversedAlg).reverse();
        algTV.setText(fullAlg.substring(pos1, pos2));

    }
```

Or this one

```
        String fullAlg = text.toString();
        String fullAldReversed = "";
        int posStart = 0, posEnd = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < fullAlg.length(); i++) {
            if (fullAlg.charAt(i) == '('){
                posStart = i;
            } else if (fullAlg.charAt(i) == ')'){
                posEnd = i;
                fullAldReversed += "(" + reverseAlg(fullAlg.substring(posStart, posEnd)) + ")";
                posStart = 0;
            }
        }
        if (posEnd == 0){
            fullAldReversed = "" + reverseAlg(fullAlg);
        }
        algTV.setText(fullAldReversed);
    }

    private StringBuilder reverseAlg(CharSequence text) {

        StringBuilder builder;
        if (!(text.charAt(0) == ' ' || text.charAt(text.length() - 1) == ' ')) {
            builder = new StringBuilder(text + " ");
        } else {
            builder = new StringBuilder(text);
        }
        int subStart = 0;
        StringBuilder auxBuilder;
        String substring = "", auxString = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < builder.length(); i++) {
            substring = "";
                int subEnd = i;
                int identifierMove = 0;
                for (int j = subStart; j <= subEnd; j++) {
                    if (builder.charAt(j) == '\'')
                        identifierMove = 1;
                    else if (builder.charAt(j) == '2')
                        identifierMove = 2;
                    else if (identifierMove == 0)
                        identifierMove = 3;
                }

                String letterMove;

                switch (identifierMove) {
                    case 1:
                        letterMove = builder.substring(subStart, subEnd - 1);
                        subStart = subEnd + 1;
                        substring = " " + letterMove;
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        letterMove = builder.substring(subStart, subEnd - 1);
                        subStart = subEnd + 1;
                        substring = " 2" + letterMove;
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        letterMove = builder.substring(subStart, subEnd);
                        subStart = subEnd + 1;
                        substring = " '" + letterMove;
                        break;
                }
            auxString += substring;
        }

        auxBuilder = new StringBuilder(auxString);
        auxBuilder.reverse().toString();
        return auxBuilder;
    }
```

Thank you!!

Comment: It may be worth noting that Java switch statements don't use regex, they only match values directly. So `case "(" + "[a-zA-Z]+":` will only match one string, `"([a-zA-Z]+"`, and not everything that regex would have matched.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry for the delay! Your attempts are quite overcomplicated in my opinion. I thought it was the best choice to make a class to represent the Rubix cube algorithm because it's a bit complicated and the class will also leave room for further expansion. Anyways, the way it works is simple. The class constructor takes a string as an input and converts the text into integers for easier storage and manipulation. From here, reversing the algorithm is super simple! All you have to do is reverse the order of the array and multiply all the integers by -1! (Their opposites i.e. R' are stored as negatives.) Then, if you want to output it as a string, you may use the toStrng() function to display the Algorithm.

```java
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;

class RubixAlg {
  //We will store our list of moves as integers. (And also parentheses) Any X' is the negative value of X
  //For example, U corresponds to 2, and U' corresponds to -2.
  ArrayList<Integer> moves = new ArrayList<Integer>();
  RubixAlg(String input){
    String input1 = input+" ";//Adding a space to the end prevents the algorithm from breaking when it checks for an apostrophe where no text exists.
    while(input1.length()>0){
      println(input1.charAt(0)); 
      //This part figures out what character is the first in the string, what move that corresponds to, and then deletes it until there's no more characters.
      switch(input1.charAt(0)){ 
        case ' ':
          input1=input1.substring(1);
          break;
        case '(':
          moves.add(1);
          input1=input1.substring(1);
          break;
        case ')':
          moves.add(-1);
          input1=input1.substring(1);
          break;
        case 'U':
          if(input1.charAt(1)=='\''){
            moves.add(-2);
            input1=input1.substring(2);
          } else {
            moves.add(2);
            input1=input1.substring(1);
          }
          break;
        case 'D':
          if(input1.charAt(1)=='\''){
            moves.add(-3);
            input1=input1.substring(2);
          } else {
            moves.add(3);
            input1=input1.substring(1);
          }
          break;
        case 'F':
          if(input1.charAt(1)=='\''){
            moves.add(-4);
            input1=input1.substring(2);
          } else {
            moves.add(4);
            input1=input1.substring(1);
          }
          break;
        case 'B':
          if(input1.charAt(1)=='\''){
            moves.add(-5);
            input1=input1.substring(2);
          } else {
            moves.add(5);
            input1=input1.substring(1);
          }
          break;
        case 'R':
          if(input1.charAt(1)=='\''){
            moves.add(-6);
            input1=input1.substring(2);
          } else {
            moves.add(6);
            input1=input1.substring(1);
          }
          break;
        case 'L':
          if(input1.charAt(1)=='\''){
            moves.add(-7);
            input1=input1.substring(2);
          } else {
            moves.add(7);
            input1=input1.substring(1);
          }
          break;
        default:
          input1=input1.substring(1);
          break;
      }
    }
  }
  String toStrng(){
    String output = "";
    for(int i=0;i<moves.size();i++){
      //println(moves.get(i));
      int move = moves.get(i);
      switch(move){
        case 1:
          output+="(";
          break;
        case -1:
          output=output.substring(0,output.length()-1);
          output+=")";
          break;
        case 2:
          output+="U ";
          break;
        case -2:
          output+="U\' ";
          break;
        case 3:
          output+="D ";
          break;
        case -3:
          output+="D\' ";
          break;
        case 4:
          output+="F ";
          break;
        case -4:
          output+="F\' ";
          break;
        case 5:
          output+="B ";
          break;
        case -5:
          output+="B\' ";
          break;
        case 6:
          output+="R ";
          break;
        case -6:
          output+="R\' ";
          break;
        case 7:
          output+="L ";
          break;
        case -7:
          output+="L\' ";
          break;
        default:
          break;
      }
    }
    return output;
  }
  void revers(){
    //What this algorithm does is pretty simple. It changes the direction by multiplying all of the stored integers by -1, and then reversing their order.
    Integer[] intermediate = new Integer[moves.size()];
    intermediate=moves.toArray(new Integer[0]);
    intermediate=ReverseNegArray(intermediate);
    for(int i=0;i<intermediate.length;i++){
      moves.set(i,intermediate[i]);
    }
  }
}
Integer[] ReverseNegArray(Integer[] x){
  Integer[] y = new Integer[x.length];
  for(int i = 1;i<=x.length;i++){
    println(-x[x.length-i]);
    y[i-1]=-x[x.length-i];
  }
  return y;
}
```

Comment: At some point I thought of doing something similar, but I was looking for a simpler algorithm which will work regardless the letter. Anyway, I think I will have to create a new class like yours, thank you!!

Comment: You could use the above solution, but instead of mapping each letter to an integer explicitly with a `switch`, you could use that letter's character code as its numeric value. That way, it doesn't limit the letters you can use, and you have less boilerplate code to write.

Answer (score 0):

I have a partial solution, that will be complete if you can convert your String representation into an Algorithm object. This represents a Rubik's cube algorithm as a sequence of individual moves, and other nested algorithms, where each move has a side and a direction (i.e. whether it is inverted or not).

```
import java.util.ArrayDeque;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Deque;

public class Rubiks
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    // (R U R' U) U' (R U' R')
    Instruction g1 = new Algorithm(Move.fore('R'), Move.fore('U'), Move.back('R'), Move.back('U'));
    Instruction g2 = new Algorithm(Move.fore('R'), Move.back('U'), Move.back('R'));
    Instruction full = new Algorithm(g1, Move.back('U'), g2);
    System.out.println("This algorithm: " + full);
    System.out.println("Inverts to be:  " + full.inverted());
  }
}

class Move implements Instruction
{
  private final char side;
  private final boolean inverse;

  private Move(final char side, final boolean inverse)
  {
    this.side = side;
    this.inverse = inverse;
  }

  public static Move fore(final char side)
  {
    return new Move(side, false);
  }
  public static Move back(final char side)
  {
    return new Move(side, true);
  }

  public Move inverted()
  {
    return new Move(side, !inverse);
  }

  @Override
  public String toString()
  {
    return side + (inverse ? "'" : "");
  }

  @Override
  public String toSubString()
  {
    return toString();
  }
}

class Algorithm implements Instruction
{
  private final Deque<Instruction> moves;

  private Algorithm(Deque<Instruction> moves)
  {
    this.moves = moves;
  }

  public Algorithm(Instruction... moves)
  {
    this.moves = new ArrayDeque<>(Arrays.asList(moves));
  }

  public Algorithm inverted()
  {
    Deque<Instruction> newMoves = new ArrayDeque<>(moves.size());
    for (Instruction instruction : (Iterable<Instruction>) moves::descendingIterator)
    {
      newMoves.add(instruction.inverted());
    }
    return new Algorithm(newMoves);
  }

  @Override
  public String toString()
  {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    boolean first = true;
    for (Instruction instruction : moves)
    {
      if(! first)
      {
        sb.append(' ');
      }
      first = false;
      sb.append(instruction.toSubString());
    }
    return sb.toString();
  }
}

interface Instruction
{
  /**
   * Returns the inverse of this instruction
   * @return an instruction that undoes this instruction
   */
  Instruction inverted();

  /**
   * Returns the string representation of the instruction, if it were nested in another instruction
   * @return the result of toString, with parentheses if this is a complex instruction
   */
  default String toSubString()
  {
    return "(" + toString() + ")";
  }
}
```

I've used the `Rubiks` class to demonstrate that it works on the initial example you provided. It outputs the following:

```
This algorithm: (R U R' U') U' (R U' R')
Inverts to be:  (R U R') U (U R U' R')
```

However I realise this answer may require you to implement more complicated logic to convert to this form if you are required to start out with a string representation of your algorithm, as parsing is not a trivial task.

Comment: Thank you! Your algorithm runs nicely!!

Answer (score 0):

After I read some answers I came up with this. Hope anyone who has the same question can get positive feedback. Thanks to everyone who tried to help me!

```
private void reverseAlg(CharSequence text) {
        StringBuilder fullAlg;
        if (!(text.charAt(0) == ' ' || text.charAt(text.length() - 1) == ' ')) {
            fullAlg = new StringBuilder(text + " ");
        } else {
            fullAlg = new StringBuilder(text);
        }
        StringBuilder reversedAlg = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 0; i < text.length(); i++) {
            if (fullAlg.charAt(i) != '(' && fullAlg.charAt(i) != ')' && fullAlg.charAt(i) != ' '
                    && fullAlg.charAt(i) != '\'' && fullAlg.charAt(i) != '2') {

                if (fullAlg.charAt(i + 1) == '\'') {

                    if (fullAlg.charAt(i + 2) == ')') {
                        reversedAlg.append(fullAlg.charAt(i)).append(")");
                    } else {
                        reversedAlg.append(fullAlg.charAt(i));
                    }

                } else if (fullAlg.charAt(i + 1) == ' ') {

                    reversedAlg.append("\'").append(fullAlg.charAt(i));

                } else if (fullAlg.charAt(i + 1) == '2') {

                    if (fullAlg.charAt(i + 2) == ')') {
                        reversedAlg.append("2").append(fullAlg.charAt(i)).append(")");
                    } else {
                        reversedAlg.append("2").append(fullAlg.charAt(i));
                    }

                } else if (fullAlg.charAt(i + 1) == ')') {

                    reversedAlg.append("\'").append(fullAlg.charAt(i)).append(")");

                }

            } else if (fullAlg.charAt(i) == ' ' || fullAlg.charAt(i) == '(') {
                reversedAlg.append(fullAlg.charAt(i));
            }
        }

        StringBuilder aux = new StringBuilder(reversedAlg.toString()).reverse();
        for (int i = 0; i < aux.length(); i++) {
            if (aux.charAt(i) == '(') {
                aux.setCharAt(i, ')');
            } else if (aux.charAt(i) == ')') {
                aux.setCharAt(i, '(');
            }
        }
        algTV.setText(aux);
    }
```